# What is the performance cost of enabling "log_lock_waits" on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locking, performance, logging, postgresql-performance

I am trying to understand what is the performance cost of enabling `log_lock_waits` on Postgres.

As per this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LOCK-WAITS), while `log_lock_waits = on`:

> Controls whether a log message is produced when a session waits longer than `deadlock_timeout` to acquire a lock. This is useful in determining if lock waits are causing poor performance. The default is `off`. Only superusers can change this setting.

But it doesn't say how much it hinders performance and I can't find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially for free, and you should enable it in all databases unless the workload is designed to have long lock waits regularly (which would be a design bug).

These error messages are written by the deadlock detector, which is expensive to run, which is why PostgreSQL doesn't run it unless someone has to wait `deadlock_timeout` seconds for a lock. 1 second is very long, so this should not happen normally (database transactions should be way shorter).

But the deadlock detector has to run anyway, and these log messages are just a side effect you get for free.